# POST to a web page with request headers in Perl

Tags: perl, http-headers, user-agent

I am trying to post data to a page with Perl, but the page also requires headers. How would I post the headers and send headers (cookies, user agents, etc)?

I tried using [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent), but I couldn't figure out how to send the headers even though I could post to the page.

One more thing about this topic. When I posted on that page and printed the response content I could see the html just fine except the numbers that were supposed to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;

my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(
    POST => "http://domain.tld/path"
);
$request->content("stuff=foobar");
$request->content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
my $response = $userAgent->request($request);

if ($response->code == 200) {
    print $response->as_string;
}
else {
   die $response->status_line;
}
```

Comment: $userAgent is not defined. Please fix the response.